# Django Rest Framework - Exclude field from related object

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have two related models and serializers for both of them. When I am serializing one of these models (the serializer has a depth of 1) the result includes some fields from the related object that should't be visible. How an I specify which serializer to use for the relation? Or is there anyway to tell Rest Framework to exclude some fields from the related object?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

I think one way would be to create an extra serializer for the model where you want to return only limited number of fields and then use this serializer in the serializer of the other model. Something like this:

```
class MyModelSerializerLimited(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('field1', 'field2')  #fields that you want to display
```

Then in the other serializer use the `MyModelSerializerLimited`:

```
class OtherModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    myfield = MyModelSerializerLimited()

    class Meta:
       model = OtherModel
       fields = ('myfield', ...)
       depth = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could override restore_fields method on serializer. Here in restore_fields method you can modify list of fields - serializer.fields - pop, push or modify any of the fields.

eg: Field workspace is read_only when action is not 'create'

```
class MyPostSerializer(ModelSerializer):

def restore_fields(self, data, files):
    if (self.context.get('view').action != 'create'):
        self.fields.get('workspace').read_only=True
    return super(MyPostSerializer, self).restore_fields(data, files)

class Meta:
    model = MyPost
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'workspace')
```